# Cassandra not returning the row of the specified primary key

Tags: nosql, cassandra

First of all, my table is structured like this:

```
CREATE TABLE timeseries_data.test_data (
    date timestamp PRIMARY KEY,
    data1 float,
    data2 float
) WITH bloom_filter_fp_chance = 0.01
    AND caching = {'keys': 'ALL', 'rows_per_partition': 'NONE'}
    AND comment = ''
    AND compaction = {'class': 'org.apache.cassandra.db.compaction.SizeTieredCompactionStrategy', 'max_threshold': '32', 'min_threshold': '4'}
    AND compression = {'chunk_length_in_kb': '64', 'class': 'org.apache.cassandra.io.compress.LZ4Compressor'}
    AND crc_check_chance = 1.0
    AND dclocal_read_repair_chance = 0.1
    AND default_time_to_live = 0
    AND gc_grace_seconds = 864000
    AND max_index_interval = 2048
    AND memtable_flush_period_in_ms = 0
    AND min_index_interval = 128
    AND read_repair_chance = 0.0
    AND speculative_retry = '99PERCENTILE';
```

With data looking like this:

```
date                             | data1 | data2
---------------------------------+-------+-------
 2018-01-01 10:27:00.000000+0000 |    15 |    30
 2018-01-01 13:47:00.000000+0000 |    94 |    45
 2018-01-01 17:14:00.000000+0000 |    13 |     3
```

I inserted a time series data for the date "2018-01-01" with the frequency in minutes. That is the data is ranging from "2018-01-01 00:00:00" to "2018-01-01 23:59:00". So in total, I have 1440 rows of data.

Problem is when I try to query for a specific date like

```
cqlsh:timeseries_data> SELECT * FROM test_data WHERE date='2018-01-01 12:00:00';
```

```
 date                            | data1 | data2
---------------------------------+-------+-------  
 2018-01-01 06:30:00.000000+0000 |    34 |    62
```

It returns a result for a different time. This probably somehow influences the count as well.

```
cqlsh:timeseries_data> SELECT count(*) FROM test_data WHERE date>='2018-01-01 00:00:00' and date<='2018-01-01 23:59:00' ALLOW FILTERING;
```

```
count
----- 
1110
```

It reports 1110 rows instead of 1440 rows.
I'm totally new to Cassandra, so any suggestions will help.
Thank you

Comment: your clock is 6:30 hours off ;)

Comment: @ypercubeᵀᴹ, Nope.

Comment: Could you try runnnng with `WHERE date='2018-01-01 12:00:00'` ?

Comment: Also, what is the timezone of the server where Cassandra is installed, the timezone setting in Cassandra and the timezone of the client you use to connect?

Comment: I was wrong, it's 5:30 hours off. (12:00 - 06:30 = 5:30) and (5x60+30 = 330). I would place a bet that you are in India timezone (but Cassandra is set to UTC).

Comment: @ypercubeᵀᴹ. The example that i have posted is the actual result and I have queried of the exact time you have asked for. And as for the timezone I'm running Cassandra on my local machine and the client is running on the same machine.

Comment: So, when you ask the query `SELECT * FROM test_data WHERE date='2018-01-01 12:00:00';`, Cassandra knows you are in IST timezone (+5:30) and thinks you want the 12:00:00 (in IST) and gives you back that (but shows the result in UTC format).

Comment: Yes, local machine but what is the timezone of the local machine? IST? And what is the timezone setting in Cassandra config? (UTC perhaps?)

Comment: Apologies, I meant this above: Could you try runnng with `WHERE date='2018-01-01T12:00:00'` ?  (note the **T**)

Comment: See here: https://docs.datastax.com/en/dse/5.1/cql/cql/cql_reference/refDateTimeFormats.html : **Note: When timezone is excluded, it's set to the client or coordinator timezone.**

Comment: @ypercubeᵀᴹ. WHERE date='2018-01-01T12:00:00' gives me exact same result as in the post. And could you please tell me how to check the timezone of Cassandra ?

Comment: **Discussion [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/98801/discussion-between-ypercube-and-yash)**.